# In Computer Science, what's the opposite of a dependency?

Tags: dependencies, computer-science, terminology

More specifically in programming, we use the term *dependency* when we are referring to a software component that is required by another piece of code to run.

What do you call that piece of code that requires the dependency to run? I don't think I know the word represent the relationship from the other way around.

Comment: What about differentiating them by calling them "dependency on" and "dependency of "?

Comment: The opposite of dependencies is "standalone" or "independent"

Comment: Yes, @Aditya, that could work but for some reason I'm looking for a single word. I think the word I'm looking for is "dependent" (component). Still doesn't sound right!

Comment: @VigneshRajendran not quite what I'm looking for cause I'm trying to refer to the "component that has a dependency". I guess I want to know how we call the component that depends on or has a dependency. It's not independent as there's a dependency relationship between the two. One is the dependency the other is the dependent?

Comment: @TheDaniel reliance - a person or thing on which someone depends.this somewhat matches but not 100%

Comment: Dependee, perhaps? https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee

Comment: The opposite of dependency is independency.  The inverse of dependency is [dependent](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248642/inverse-of-dependency). This is commonly used in many engineering disciplines and has the advantage of being an English word, whereas "depender" is jargon that is not widely used and will cause additional questions whenever someone wants to disambiguate with a dictionary.   I cannot really understand why an answer with "Dependent" was downvoted and deleted with the motive that it was not specific enough to programming...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The *opposite* of a dependency is independency.

The *inverse* of a dependency is a **dependent**. This term applies specifically in programming to refer to the piece of code that requires the dependency to run.

---

The term is widely used. Some quotes to support the claim:

- In the book *Dependency Injection: Design patterns using Spring and Guice* (so a book that is mainly about dependencies in the programming context):

  > Dependency — A specific service that is required by another object to fulfill its function.
  > Dependent — A client object that needs a dependency (or dependencies) in order to perform its function.
- In the book *The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual, 2nd ed* by Booch, Rumbaugh and Jacobson:

  > Dependency:  A relationship between two elements in which a change to one element (the supplier) may affect or supply information needed by the other element (the client). (...) the dependent elements are called clients.
- In the [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/#why-use-semantic-versioning) manifesto,  they explain how semver can allow to release new versions of dependencies without disrupting dependent software or packages.
- In the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) of Maven:

  > Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
- Last but not least, [linguist](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248642/inverse-of-dependency) have also confirmed suitability of this term for very similar dependency management needs.

Dependency being a relation between something that is dependent and something that it depends on, there is a little residual ambiguity on the direction that is meant.  Regardless the terms used, it's recommended to provide the definitions.  Supplier/Client are alternatives that are imho more easily understood although not universally suitable.

Answer (score 9):

From the body of your question :

> What do you call that piece of code that requires the dependency

The **Depender**

Example :

The depender had a dependency on the dependee, that's when the problems started.

Source :

I just needed this info myself and found this : [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee#:~:text=Noun,used%20in%20agent-oriented%20programming](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee#:%7E:text=Noun,used%20in%20agent-oriented%20programming))

Comment: I checked that too but it says it is usually reserved for AOP. I guess this is the closest we will get.